# can an Azure-hosted SQL Server connect with an Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

Not sure if this is an option?  Ideally looking at something like an openrowset query from a stored procedure within SQL server or a web job.

If so, are there any resources available to help learn how to make SQL Server and Cosmos play nicely together?

Comment: Is Azure Data Factory an option? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db. You can use `BULK INSERT` to insert blobs into SQL Azure. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/preview-loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-sql-database/ . To do what you want you need this to support CosmosDB as a source (I don't think it does at the moment)

Comment: yeah I'm messing around with ADF right now and looking at ways to integrate ADF within our existing resources, specifically looking to connect SQL Server and Cosmos though

Comment: Depending on the level and complexity of orchestration / triggering / data integration, you should seriously consider using ADF. For example there is no scheduler (i.e. SQL Agent) in SQL Azure. If you have a scheduling and integration requirement in SQL Azure then ADF is the answer. ADF does have limitations but it's coming along nicely.

Comment: You cannot query a Cosmos DB from any of the Azure PaaS SQL options. You cannot use linked servers in case of Azure Managed Instances, You cannot case elastic queries (cross database queries) of Azure SQL Database to query Cosmos DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your SQL Server in Azure is managed by you on a VM (IaaS) you should be able to add the Cosmos DB as "SQL Server Linked Server" e.g. by adding as ODBC Source.
Then it's also optional if you link the Cosmos DB PaaS service to your Vnet or access it via public endpoints.

Not 100% sure if this will also succeed with Azure managed instances (which is quite new in GA).

Comment: I'm Paas with Azure SQL Server and exploring Cosmos options, does that help?

Comment: I think there is no current solution for PaaS SQL -> Cosmos DB. Probably you also googled a lot without results before writing this question? :)

Comment: I sure did!  I was hoping there was a way but no such luck it seems.

Comment: when things change (and they change fast in Azure!!!) and I get notice, I'll remember to edit this answer!